# Provider not working unless the dependent provider were defined with "deps" property

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm trying to use an angular service that I created in an independent library called *HttpService*. I'm using this service in another angular service in my current project, its name is *IdentityService*. I'm trying to inject *HttpService* onto *IdentityService* but angular always says **NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpService!**.

I've defined somewhat like this in my *app.module.ts*:

```js
import { HttpService } from '@my-http';
... some more imports

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     ...
  ],
  imports: [
     ...
  ],
  providers: [
    IdentityService,
    HttpService
  ],
  exports: [...],
  bootstrap: [...],
  schemas: [...],
  entryComponents: [...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

That gives me the error **NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpService!** when trying to inject *HttpService* in *IdentityService* constructor.

Then, I changed it over like this:

```js
import { HttpService } from '@my-http';
... some more imports

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     ...
  ],
  imports: [
     ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: IdentityService,
      useClass: IdentityService,
      deps: [HttpService]
    },
    HttpService
  ],
  exports: [...],
  bootstrap: [...],
  schemas: [...],
  entryComponents: [...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And that actually works!

I tried to replicate that behavior in a test project and couldn't. In the test project, *Dependency Injection* works as expected and angular don't make me set **deps** attribute, so that the first way of defining providers works.

I would like to understand what are possible reasons why that's angular's behavior, make one set **deps** attribute in order to work.

Comment: Did You try first declare `HttpService` then `IdentityService` ? Remember usually compilers read code from top to bottom so when he read `IdentityService` he culd dont know about there will be `HttpService`.

Comment: @Mises yes, I did and it didn't work

Comment: This HttpService is only for http calls ?

Comment: You know that when You making independent library You need to build it in module ? And import module not services ?

Comment: @Mises I did what you said about putting my service in the module and importing it and the result has been the same

Comment: Becouse You import modules not services. You need to provide service in module and import this module to project.

Comment: I just can assuming what You did wrong when i don't see code. XD

Comment: @Mises what is different from that isolated test that I did is that in my project I'm working with lazy loading, but as you can see I added both providers directly in the app.module, so that I don't know whether those providers continue available in the lazy loaded module

Comment: Try to add them to lazy loding modules to.